# Get current space category in confluence refinedwiki Original Theme Header

Tags: velocity, confluence

We are using Confluence for our technical documentation and [refinedwiki Original Theme Plugin](http://www.refinedwiki.com/en/display/products/original-theme-confluence.aspx) to customize the design. Documentation is available in two languages (German, English). Spaces are organized as follows:

Category: "German"

- Space: "Product 1 - DE"
- Space: "Product 2 - DE"

Category: "English"

- Space: "Product 1 - EN"
- Space: "Product 2 - EN"

In the site header, I'd like to place links to Product 1 Home, Product 2 Home, ... in current language. (I try to modify the site header using the textbox provided by OriginalTheme > [Manage custom design](http://demo.refinedwiki.com/display/rwot3x/Design+your+wiki).)

That means:

If the current page is in a space that has category "German":

- Link: "Product 1" => Space "Product 1 - DE" - Home

Else

- Link: "Product 1" => Space "Product 1 - EN" - Home

I understand that I can use Velocity functions so a simple if should do the job if I could get information about the current space.

How can I access the category of current space?

Comment: When you say "site header" do you mean the Menu Bar which includes universal links for the entire space or do you mean you are trying to insert links in the area at the very top of your page? I might just be confused because I have never used refinedwiki.

Comment: Could you just use different layouts for the English spaces and the German spaces? That way the two different layouts could have the correct links for each language.

Comment: @MNRSullivan You're right. simply using two layouts will do the job. You made my day ;-)

Comment: I'm glad that helped. I'll make an answer, please accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two different customized layouts for the English spaces and the German spaces. That way the two custom layouts can have the correct links for each language.

To customize layouts, go to Edit -> Administration -> Edit Layout

This page might help get you headed in the right direction:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Customising+Site+and+Space+Layouts

Comment: When using the RefinedWiki Plug-In it's not possible to assign different themes to spaces, but you can assign a theme to a category (so so to all spaces in this category).